# Problem with a mongodb database using mongoose and express js, following a tutorial

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Problem with a mongodb database using mongoose and express js, following a tutorial

The tutorial can be found here [Tutortial Angular6 MEAN Stack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a30flH_q5-A)

My **server.js** file content

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Issue from './models/Issue';

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/issues', { useNewUrlParser: true });

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open',  () =>{
    console.log("MongoDB connection established successfully");
});


router.route('/issues').get( (req, res) => {
    Issue.find((err,issues) => {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            res.json(issues); 
    });
});
```

My **Issue.js** file content

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Issue = new Schema ({

    title: {
        type: String
    },

    responsible: {
        type: String
    },

    description: {
        type: String
    },

    severity: {
        type: String
    },

    status: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Open'
    }

});

export default mongoose.model('Issue', Issue);
```

I also have my Issue collection with valid json data, but when I try to visit the url [localhost:4000/issues](http://localhost:4000/issues), I get just an empty []

Also here are my permissions for data/db

```
ls -ail
total 12
656701 drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 oct 15 18:56 .
     2 drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 oct 15 18:56 ..
658216 drwxrwxrwx  4 dan  root 4096 oct 16 11:29 db
```

Can someone point me into the right direction?
Thank you

Comment: Is there any data in the "Issue" collection?

Comment: Yes I have sample data in the issue collection

Comment: Issue != issue (case sensitivity is important).

Comment: I verified that, would it help if i post also my mongodb and some sample data?

Comment: Yes. The best thing to get would be a command line log from connecting, selecting the DB, to reading the Issue collection (commands and output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @str mentioned the mongodb database is case sensitive so I made a mistake when i created my database in mongo.

I named my database **Issues** instead of **issues** so I had to use the following commands to solve it:

```
mongodump -d Issues -o mongodump/
use Issues
db.dropDatabase()
mongorestore -d issues mongodump/Issues
```

Thank you for the right pointers @str